# Creating a responsive, fringed (repeating triangles) css border

Tags: html, css, flexbox, pseudo-class

I've been working on a pattern for a while which calls for a fringed bottom border on a modal. The problem, is that depending on the viewport size, my current implementation cuts of one side, which is less than ideal.

Here's where the inspiration came from, Google's Wallet app, which implements this via an :after pseudoclass, an image background and  repeats. You can see that the edges are cut off:

```
.receipt-main-section::after {
background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAICAYAAADA+m62AAAAkklEQ…MUwBTzA7EIEAtBFbEgK0JWDLKCA6oJqyIGqCAjVAMTuiIAuCdhjWF6oYAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) 0 0 repeat-x;
content: "";
height: 8px;
margin: 12px 0 0 -22px;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;}
```

[image: Google wallet fringe border]

Here is my CSS implementation, which also breaks on the edges:

[image: css fringe implementation]

http://jsfiddle.net/n28pa3dy/1/

How can one implement this concept in a way that can handle different widths while maintaining a consistent ratio of fringes, and thus not breaking on the edges?

Answer (score 3):

you can use linear-gradient and background-size:

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  background:black;
  display:flex;
}
body {
  min-height:50%;
    color:white;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  font-size:4vw;
  align-items:center;
  padding-bottom:2vw;
  width:50vw;
  margin: auto;
  background:
    linear-gradient(45deg , transparent 2vw, gray 2vw) ,
    linear-gradient(-45deg , transparent 2vw, gray 2vw) ,
    linear-gradient(45deg , transparent 1.8vw, lightgray 1.8vw) ,
    linear-gradient(-45deg , transparent 1.8vw, white 1.8vw);
  background-size: 1vw calc(100% + 1.5vw);
  border:0.2vw solid white;
  border-bottom:none;
}
```

```html
you may use vw units ...
```

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  background:yellow;
}
body {
  min-height:50%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(45deg , transparent 4em, gray 4em),
    linear-gradient(-45deg , transparent 4em, gray 4em),
    linear-gradient(45deg , transparent 3.5em, lightgray 3.8em),
    linear-gradient(-45deg , transparent 3.5em, lightgray 3.8em);
  background-size: 5.5em 100%;
}
```

you may break bg-position to make more funny shapes ...

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  background:yellow;
}
body {
  min-height:50%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(45deg , transparent 4em, gray 4em) center,
    linear-gradient(-45deg , transparent 4em, gray 4em) ,
    linear-gradient(45deg , transparent 3.5em, lightgray 3.8em) center,
    linear-gradient(-45deg , transparent 3.5em, lightgray 3.8em);
  background-size: 5.5em 100%;
}
```

and so on :) ....

Comment: Some interesting concepts here, but I'm not able to see how the implementations you listed increment the ridges to avoid the edging issue. Perhaps I've overlooked it, so I'll try them out.

Comment: @G.Mart i added a border and tune first snippet  so selecting an even width or/and background-size you should have the amount of triangle wished at the bottom and a border going sides and top

Comment: Ok, I tested this, but I'm afraid I can't accept this answer, though it present great concepts, as the fringe distorts greatly at smaller screen sizes. This was an excellent answer despite that though!

Comment: @G.Mart it is yours , i'll be interresting when you find a way that suits your needs :)

Comment: @GCyrullis, I'll keep you posted, perhaps we can both find the answer here!