# CSS linear-gradient funky appearence

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I tried to create bottom triangle "border" with linear-gradient since I don't want to use image. Well, something funky happens. It appears good only in Firefox, any other browsers have problem. What's happening? I need help. The added part is colored for better view. If there are better ways with the same effect, please show me. Thanks.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxcpO.png)

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body {
            background: #403434;
        }
        #box {
            width: 55%;
            margin: 50px auto;
            background: #eee;
            height: 300px;
            position: relative;
        }
        #box:before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -15px; 
            width: 100%; height: 15px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, #c37e2e 0),
                linear-gradient(135deg, #c37e2e 50%, transparent 0);    
            background-size: 15px 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">  
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: it is because the math rouding values are not the same, change value of gradient, so they overlap enough to not see this happening and not break the design out desired

Comment: maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733392/creating-a-responsive-fringed-repeating-triangles-css-border/35733579